# How does orphanRemoval=true work in JPA 2.0

Tags: java, jpa

Can I just check how orphanRemoval=true works?  Is it a SQL operation, i.e. the database is checked for orphans after the changes are merged.  Or is it an in memory operation which tracks that an object has been removed from the collection, therefore it must be deleted?

What are the mechanics?

For example if two people are editing the same data and both have an entity x.collectionY and collectionY has items with an ID of 1,2,3,4 in it...then when both users are working in the application they have the same start point.  If user 1 adds item 5,6,7 and then user 2 commits...because 5,6,7 are not part of their collection what happens?

Also, what if you swap one collection out for another in a backing bean, how does this affect the tracking.

Sorry for the basic questions, but if it was a SQL operation I would be OK and understand it, but need to get my head round it as we are using it quite heavily at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove a reference to an entity by nulling it out or having it reference something different, JPA orphan removal requires providers to delete the dereferenced entity.  This is provider specific, so I'm not sure what exactly you need to know - anything left orphaned is required by the spec to be deleted.  Your questions on multiple users editing the same data does not really apply to orphan removal - they are general problems with synchronous data access.  These changes should conflict with each other regardless of orphan removal being involved, so you should be using some form of locking, with optimistic locking being the most common.

If there is no locking, there is a good chance they could overwrite data with stale data and cause entities to be removed, for instance if user 2 detached its instance and then tries to merge its now stale object into the entity manager.   At the end, one transaction will overwrite the other without some form of locking.

There are a number of blogs and docs you can find describing locking, the simplest I use is http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Mapping/Locking/Optimistic_Locking

Comment: Hi,  thanks.  I guess my concern is if its an in memory operation.  User a has an object with items 1,2,3 in the collection.  User 2 opens sames instance and adds 4,5,6 to the same collection.  Both users now have different in memory views of the entity - one with a collection containing 1,2,3 and one containing 1,2,3,4,5,6.  If user 2 commits and then user 1 commits, as it is in memory  - does JPA think that because items 4,5,6 are in the database and seem linked to the entity - but are not in the user 1 In Memory Collection (1,2,3) then 4,5,6 get deleted.  This is different from locking.

Comment: Nothing happens until they commit, and one commit always goes first.  You cannot share an EntityManager on multiple threads, so each user has a different managed instance to make its changes on - they are or should be separate transactions and views of the data, and so make changes independent of one another.  They need locking to prevent overwriting changes with stale data, completely independent of orphan removal.  What happens with orphan removal is the exact same thing that happens when changing any field if you are merging in stale entities without locking- last one wins.

Comment: so in this example would user 2's late commit cause items 4,5,6 for user 2 to be deleted because they are not part of user 1s in memory collection at the time of commit - via orphanRemoval?

Comment: If you are allowing concurrent changes and are not locking, you are asking for trouble.  The last one's view of the collection wins - calling merge on an entity referencing only items 4,5 and 6 should cause the others to be removed if they exist when merge is called.  The provider has to know about them to remove them.  So it depends on a whole bunch of specifics you left out of your example - when each was read, where, when each is committed etc.  There is a chance it will work one way, and a chance it will work another, which is why you need some form of locking when using data concurrently

Comment: just want to understand the mechanics.  If JPA does this when orphanRemoval=true for user 1 (Delete from table where ID of many table IN (IDs in my in memory collection)), then we lose 4,5,6.

Comment: I did not explain this well.  Ignore orphan removal, as it will behave the exact same way for a relationship as it would for a basic field.  If user1 changes a name, while user2 doesn't, what do you expect will happen?  Is the name changed or not?  All depends on how user2 does things and when, as it very well could cause the name change to be undone.  Orphan removal will work the same way.  If user2 merges in a stale collection into one that has the changes, the new object will be removed.

Comment: thanks, that's clear...also thanks for optimistic lock link, seems simple enough to implement.  I assume with optimistic locking it doesnt matter if something was changed in a lazy loaded relationship that never got loaded.